# Unable to resolve non Maven artifacts when using a Maven package feed of vsts

Tags: maven, azure-devops, ivy, azure-artifacts

I have created a Maven feed via the VSTS package management and deployed all my necessary jars into the package which will be used to resolve all dependencies in my project during ivy ant build through ibiblio resolvers.
The problem that I am facing is that all jars that are available in the Maven central repository and also deployed to my Maven package get resolved through my defined ivy resolvers, but when I have custom jars for e.g. a jar that is the war of a internal project or jars that are not present in Maven central repository which were downloaded from their respective sites, I get the unresolved dependencies error. The url that is unresolvable as stated in the build failure during ivy resolve step works fine when accessed from the browser, (jar gets downloaded onto my local drive) but during my ant build the ivy resolve step which looks for the non-Maven jars in the Maven package that was created always fails.

I made a few changes as in when creating the package I opted for the "Packages from public sources" option as "Only use packages published to this feed" but it still does not resolve those specific jars.

The reason for my creating the Maven package management feed is so that instead of referring to the Maven repository I can host all my jars in this feed both maven and non-maven and resolve all dependencies by only referring to this feed.

Can someone please point out whether I am doing something wrong or if the concept that I am trying to implement is flawed. 
Any input will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, to deploy the jars (maven & custom) into the maven feed, the following command has been used - mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=[groupId] -DartifactId=[artifactId] -Dversion=[version] -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=[repoId] -Durl=[mavenFeedurl] -Dfile=[jar location on local drive]

Comment: This seems more related to maven side not VSTS. VSTS just offer the package management. If you agree with it, you could move the VSTS tag.

Comment: Before moving the dependencies to VSTS maven feed, I was referring to the custom jars from a local ivy repo and it worked fine. The issue about not being able to resolve these custom jars during build occurred when I started using the Maven feed as the dependency repo. If I include all my dependencies into the source code and make changes to the pointing in my resolvers it works fine. 
What I cannot figure out is why are custom jars deployed to the remote maven feed not resolved correctly in spite of them being present in the feed.